# How can I enforce black's `--preview` option when invoking black with pre-commit?

Tags: python, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, python-black

I just found out that `black`'s default behavior for long logfile messages does not enforce a maximum line length. I have verified that I can enforce max line length if I invoke black manually (v 23.1.0, in a Python 3.9.9 venv). Now I'd like to make sure that enforcement happens with every commit, using pre-commit, but I don't know how to do this.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this isn't specific to `black` -- any tool can add arguments in pre-commit by utilizing `args`

taking black's base config:

```yaml
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: ...  # use your revision here
    hooks:
    -   id: black
        args: [--preview]
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit, I've contributed to black